# How to escape a special character in the output of a variable

Tags: bash, shell, applescript

Trying to compile an add printer command using lpadmin and running it via an Apple Script. The issue I am facing is the printer name has the special Character & and looks like this

PRINTERVALUE: DellB&W

do shell script "lpadmin -p " & PRINTERVALUE & " -E -v LPD://" & PRINTERVALUE & " -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/DellBW.ppd.gz  -o printer-is-shared=false"

This gives me an error and the command halts at special character & since is part of the Printer name.. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `quoted form of`, it adds the necessary escape characters:

```
do shell script "lpadmin -p " & quoted form of PRINTERVALUE & " -E -v LPD://" & quoted form of PRINTERVALUE & " -P /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/DellBW.ppd.gz -o printer-is-shared=false"
```

Answer (score -1):

In general escape char is: \

Try something like this:

```
PRINTERVALUE: DellB\&W
```

or in quotes:

```
PRINTERVALUE: "DellB\&W"
```